# Fatal error: SQLSTATE[22007] PHP 7 Mysql PDO

Tags: mysql, php7, pdo, update, double

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo un Update en una tabla de Mysql, son dos campos numericos, pero me da este error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '50712-
```

```
$JockUpd = "Update turf_cabll Set idjockey = ?  where idcabll = ? ";

    $JockeyUpdate = $conn->prepare($JockUpd); // Se crea un objeto PDOStatement.    

            $JockeyUpdate->bindParam(1, $idjoc ); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.
            $JockeyUpdate->bindParam(2, $idcab); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.

if ( $JockeyUpdate->execute())  {
   echo "<font color=green>Actualización Jockey en Caballo exitosa</font><br>";

} else {
   echo "<font color=green>Un error ocurrió actualizando Jockey en Caballo</font><br>";

}
```

Los valores de las Variables idjoc= 1098 y el de $idcab= 50712

La tabla tiene un campo donde guarda la fecha de alta

El error lo da al ejecutar, lo extraño es que en otra página funciona sin dar ningún error

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato esperas en las variables, por que el error indica que los tipos no funcionan entonces esperas pasar una fecha o un double?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero poder ayudarte, y si en las lineas:

```
$JockeyUpdate->bindParam(1, $idjoc ); // Se asigna una variable para la consulta.
$JockeyUpdate->bindParam(2, $idcab); // Se asigna un valor para la consulta.
```

Le especificas el tercer parametro a los bindParam para especificar el tipo de valor:

```
$JockeyUpdate->bindParam(1, $idjoc, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$JockeyUpdate->bindParam(2, $idcab, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Excelente, funcionó perfecto

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias